# Trouble with data merge

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm having a hard time getting data from my code into the template using the c# library.

I have a template setup that I added a text box to using the online template edit tool.  I'm trying to update the value of that text box with it's Data Label.  Could I get a c# example of this?

This is the snippet from my current code:

```
Text name = new Text();
name.TabLabel = "Data Label";
name.Value = "My Name";
tRole.Tabs = new EnvelopeRecipientTabs();
tRole.Tabs.TextTabs = new List<Text>();
tRole.Tabs.TextTabs.Add(name);

List<TemplateRole> rolesList = new List<TemplateRole>() { tRole };
envDef.TemplateRoles = rolesList;
```

I have tried some of the comments and questions and this is what I have now:

C#

```
//define signer            
TemplateRole signer1 = new TemplateRole();
signer1.Name = "John Doe";
signer1.Email = "BOB@AOL.COM";
signer1.RoleName = "Owner";

//populate envelope object
EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition();
envelopeDefinition.TemplateId = "bd417d79-2a0b-4d76-8970-e2d18451c2f5";
envelopeDefinition.Status = "created";
envelopeDefinition.EmailSubject = "eSign";

//create text tab object
Text text1 = new Text();
text1.TabLabel = "FullName";
text1.Value = "EP";

//apply tab to signer
signer1.Tabs = new Tabs();
signer1.Tabs.TextTabs = new List<Text>();
signer1.Tabs.TextTabs.Add(text1);

//apply signer 
List<TemplateRole> templateroles = new List<TemplateRole>() { signer1 };
envelopeDefinition.TemplateRoles = templateroles;

// execute it
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = await envelopesApi.CreateEnvelopeAsync(account.accountId, envelopeDefinition);
return envelopeSummary.EnvelopeId;
```

JSON

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net:7801/restapi/v2/accounts/4794997/envelopes

TraceToken: fe59bc72-61f3-4c07-9eeb-0d53d558437a
Timestamp: 2018-05-21T18:36:48.4260253Z

Content-Length: 255
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept: application/json
Host: demo.docusign.net
X-DocuSign-SDK: C#
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"[omitted]", "Password":"[omitted]", "IntegratorKey":"[omitted]"}
x-ms-request-root-id: dba2cd44-40b5e3581ae1a62d
x-ms-request-id: |dba2cd44-40b5e3581ae1a62d.2.
Request-Id: |dba2cd44-40b5e3581ae1a62d.2.
X-SecurityProtocol-Version: TLSv1.2
X-SecurityProtocol-CipherSuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
x-forwarded-for: 24.1.74.183

{"emailSubject":"eSign With Payment From API","status":"created","templateId":"bd417d79-2a0b-4d76-8970-e2d18451c2f5","templateRoles":[{"email":"BOB@AOL.COM","name":"John Doe","roleName":"Owner","tabs":{"textTabs":[{"tabLabel":"FullName","value":"EP"}]}}]}
201 Created
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-DocuSign-TraceToken: fe59bc72-61f3-4c07-9eeb-0d53d558437a

{
  "envelopeId": "13fb444c-79cc-43bb-b6d4-3a6241c84ebc",
  "uri": "/envelopes/13fb444c-79cc-43bb-b6d4-3a6241c84ebc",
  "statusDateTime": "2018-05-21T18:36:46.9570000Z",
  "status": "created"
}
```

Data Label https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lo1dx.jpg

Recipient https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtrNH.jpg

Comment: I would request you to capture API logs after hitting DS platform, it will have actual JSON request which is sent to DocuSign. You can capture it by following steps as explained [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging), once you have captured then paste it on your qs so that we can see the actual issue.

Comment: I have updated the question with the JSON, thanks for sharing that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name.TabLabel` property needs to exactly match the label used in your template. So, for example, if your tag was set up like this:

[image: tagger]

you would use `name.TabLabel = "Text1";`. Setting `name.Value = "My Name";` would then populate that tag with 'My Name', assuming your template is being referenced and your signer is mapped to the template role.

Code sample for sending from a template with tags populated follows. This assumes the signer role name is "Signer 1" and the tag label is "Text 1"

```
        //define signer            
        TemplateRole signer1 = new TemplateRole();
        signer1.Name = "Example User";
        signer1.Email = "user@example.com";
        signer1.RoleName = "Signer 1";

        //populate envelope object
        EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition();
        envelopeDefinition.TemplateId = "xxx-yyy-zzz"; // Replace with template ID
        envelopeDefinition.Status = "created"; //generates draft instead of immediately sending

        //create text tab object
        Text text1 = new DocuSign.eSign.Model.Text();
        text1.TabLabel = "Text1";
        text1.Value = "Example Text";

        //apply tab to signer
        signer1.Tabs = new Tabs();
        signer1.Tabs.TextTabs = new List<DocuSign.eSign.Model.Text>();
        signer1.Tabs.TextTabs.Add(text1);

        //apply signer 
        List<TemplateRole> templateroles = new List<TemplateRole>() { signer1 };
        envelopeDefinition.TemplateRoles = templateroles;

        //create EnvelopesApi object
        EnvelopesApi template = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient.Configuration);

        //execute envelope generation
        EnvelopeSummary response = template.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envelopeDefinition);
```

Comment: I tried this out, and still no luck.  I updated my question with the updated code.  Thanks for the help, I feel like I'm close now!

Comment: @Eric - I was able to check this internally, and it looks like your template role has a burned-in name and email, so the recipient you're adding in the API call isn't able to map to that. Blank out the name/email so the template role is a placeholder and it should work.

Comment: Thanks again, but if I don't have a recipient set for the template it doesn't let me map the fields.  Even though I do want to sent it to the person I'm via the code.

Comment: The Role needs to exist and needs to have a Role Name, but it shouldn't have a Recipient Name or Email in the template.

Comment: Thanks Drew that got it

Answer (score 0):

You are creating envelope in the `created` status, and Signer will not be able to see the dataLabel value for a `draft` envelope as Signer does not have access to the envelope for a `draft` envelope. You need to create/update envelope with the `sent` status, once Signer starts the signing ceremony then he/she will be seeing the pre-populated text tab value.

Comment: You can definitely pre-populate tags in a Draft and then go and view those values prior to sending the envelope.

Comment: The one you are referring to is a Sender View not the signer's view. The one I am referring to is Signer's view that Signer cannot see anything for a draft envelope as it has not reached him. Let me edit my answer by explicitly saying it Signer's view.